# Best way to program such things " writing the code " :: Qt

Tags: c++, qt

can you guys help me with these questions and give your opinion.

1- let's say I want to create a window that maybe calculate something " any window " is it ok if I write most of the stuff in the constructor instead of creating a function that does it for me then call it in the constrictor ? or which is the better approach.

2- let's say I have an array or qvector or anything , with maybe +30 elements , those elements are meant to be constant maybe like holding subjects names "I want to insert the names not the user", is it considered bad to initialize it like this:

```
s[0]=".."
s[1]="...."
```

since I can't use a loop because the names will change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1- let's say I want to create a window that maybe calculate something " any window " is it ok if I write most of the stuff in the constrictor instead of creating a function that does it for me then call it in the constrictor ? or which is the better approach.

I would tell you that *any* function should be small, not just the constructor. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256453/what-is-the-advantage-of-breaking-a-code-into-several-small-functions-in-c) might help.

> 2- let's say I have an array or qvector or anything , with maybe +30 elements , those elements are meant to be constant maybe like holding subjects names " I want to insert the names not the user " , is it considered bad to inizilize it like this :
>
> s[0]=".." s[1]="...." . . .
>
> since I can't use a loop because the names will change.

Consider specifying these values in an external configuration file, which you would then load (i.e. parse) when the application starts. That is, instead of having tons of statements like

```
s[0] = "john doe"
s[1] = "jane doe
// ...
```

put those names in a file, say `names.cfg`, and fill in your `QVector` like this:

```
std::ifstream in{"names.cfg"};

QVector<std::string> names;
std::string current_name;

while (std::getline(in, current_name))
    names.push_back(current_name);
```

Disclaimer: I'm no Qt expert, but I think the use of `QVector` is valid.

Comment: Thank you for your help , and I did what you said  and put the info in a text file and read it using qfile.

Answer (score 1):

1 - yes, it is bad practice to do all the work in the constr**u**ctor. Constructors are there to initialize your object, not to hold your entire application.

2 - for initializing a `QVector` see this: https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/32927 ... Should work for `QString` too, not only `int`.