# Which one is better, conditional for loop or for loop with a break (for short block of code)?

Tags: java, for-loop, break

I am trying to find out which practices make your code more readable, specifically when your block of the code is short. Please look at these two versions of the for loop and let me know which one is more readable;

```
    private boolean isValid(String guessInput)
    {
        boolean result = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < guessInput.length(); i++)
        {
            if (!Character.isDigit(guessInput.charAt(i)))
            {
                result = false;
                break;

            }
        }if (result)
        {
            int guessInputInt = Integer.parseInt(guessInput);
            if (guessInputInt >= minGuess && guessInputInt < maxGuess)
                guesses.add(guessInput);
            else
                result = false;

        }else
            System.out.println("Your input is not valid.");

        return result;
    }
```

Version 2

```
    private boolean isValid(String guessInput)
    {
        boolean result = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < guessInput.length() && result; i++)
        {
            if (!Character.isDigit(guessInput.charAt(i)))
            {
                result = false;

            }
        }if (result)
        {
            int guessInputInt = Integer.parseInt(guessInput);
            if (guessInputInt >= minGuess && guessInputInt < maxGuess)
                guesses.add(guessInput);
            else
                result = false;

        }else
            System.out.println("Your input is not valid.");

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This seems more like a question for "Code Review" rather than "StackOverflow". However in that particular case, a `break` would be preferable as there is no reason to continue with the loop at that point.

Comment: Frankly, the readability and design problems are, IMO, not really related with break vs. no break. I'd rather concentrate on code formatting, spacing , systematic usage of curly braces, and giving a single responsibility instead of 3 to your method: it checks if the input is valid, but also prints an error message, and also has an unexpected side effect of mofifying the guesses field. It should only do what its name says: returning a boolean indicating if the input is valid or not. See https://gist.github.com/jnizet/14c6276fcb9225422f90425f4e7fdaca for a better formatting example

Answer (score 0):

Approach to `break` the loop is better amongst the two. Also, you can move the `Sysout` statement inside the loop e.g.:

```
private boolean isValid(String guessInput){

for (int i = 0; i < guessInput.length() && result; i++){
   if (!Character.isDigit(guessInput.charAt(i))){
        return false;
   }
}
return true;
```

**Update**

Here's another way to do it (using java 8 stream):

```
public static boolean isValid(String s){
    return !s.chars()
            .filter(c -> !Character.isDigit((char)c))
            .findFirst()
            .isPresent();
}
```

Agreed with Mark Jeronimus's point. You should call this method and `print` the messages in calling the method rather than having `Sysout` in the valildating method.

Comment: It's better to separate responsibilities. Checking validity and reporting validity are separate. I was going to suggest splitting up the method in a method that checks validity and returns boolean (takes care of the break) and one that acts on it. Then I saw that the original method was already intended as such, and moreover that the approach is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How about a third option:

```
private boolean isValid(String guessInput) {
    boolean result = isNumeric(guessInput);
    if (result)
    // ...
}

private boolean isNumeric(String input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < guessInput.length(); i++)
        if (!Character.isDigit(guessInput.charAt(i)))
            return false;

    return !input.isEmpty();
}
```

Or even simpler:

```
private boolean isValid(String guessInput) {
    try {
        int guessInputInt = Integer.parseInt(guessInput);
        if (guessInputInt >= minGuess && guessInputInt < maxGuess) {
            guesses.add(guessInput);
            return true;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.println("Your input is not valid.");
    }
    return false;
}
```

On a side note, the method name `isValid()` implies a read-only getter, which is very misleading when you're modifying state.

Answer (score 0):

For this I like the use of

```
public boolean isValid(String s) {
    if (isNum(s)) {
        Integer num = Integer.parseInt(s);
        return inRange(num, maxGuess, minGuess);
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean inRange(Integer i, Integer max, Integer min) {
    return (i < max && i >= min);
}

private boolean isNum(String s) {
    return s.chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit);
}
```

As others have mentioned `System.out.println("Your input is not valid.");` is best done by the consumer of the `isValid` function,

Breaking `isValid` into smaller operations helps with **MURDER**!

You can read about murder [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256453/what-is-the-advantage-of-breaking-a-code-into-several-small-functions-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

In your loops, if you can accurately specify your loop breaking condition in the for loop itself, that is always better.

I always think of `break` as a hack/patch/fix, never a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically to the question on the usage of break in the loop in your example, I don't think there is a difference in code readability, since it is so short.

However, in general I would prefer the break approach, because:

1. There is no reason to continue execution once the result is set to false. Depending on the length of "guessInput", and how the compiler may optimize your code, the code with break can be a lot more efficient.
2. Although the code inside for loop is short in your example, in practice it may likely to grow as the condition become more complex.  By always breaking out of the loop where it should, it will become a lot easier follow the code logic when the code inside loop becomes longer or more complex.

Therefore, I would always prefer to use break where it should in a loop.

Comment: Regarding your first point, both examples do terminate when `result` is false.

Answer (score -1):

If your intention is to validate numbers, any numbers, then you'd use the API for that, and handle the exception if the number is invalid.

Caveat: In your code, if your string is over 2147483647, the exception is thrown anyway and *unhandled*, leading to bugs.

Here's a better version, although I'd still argue about splitting up responsibilities in a pure checking method and another method that adds it to the guesses and/or prints stuff.

```
private boolean isValid(String guessInput)
{
    try {
        int guessInputInt = Integer.parseInt(guessInput);
        if (guessInputInt >= minGuess && guessInputInt < maxGuess) {
            guesses.add(guessInput);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        System.out.println("Your input is not valid.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This will return `true` regardless of the range check.