# Nested functions and its usefulness, functions that call one after another?

Tags: c, function, nested

I have seen people write code in this fashion:

```
void function2()
{.....
..more blah blah...
.<I think i will stop nesting my function here>...
..blah blah. over and out....
}

void function1()
{.....
..blah blah...
function2();
....
}

void LCD_disp_main ()
{
<automatic, static... variable declaration>
....
function1(); //calling a function 1
.....
}
```

as opposed to writing the definitions that you would normally put in function and put it inline here.

```
   void LCD_disp_main ()
    {
    <automatic, static... variable declaration>
    ....
    <function1() and function2();> //instead of calling function1 and fucntion2 just inline it here.
    .....
    }
```

What is the benefit of one over the other?
Doesn't the first set cause the stack to keep growing everytime you call a new function albeit it will grow the same mount in option 2? Context switching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's for readability, maintainability and obeying the convention that a function should do one thing only and do it well and lots of [other benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256453/what-is-the-advantage-of-breaking-a-code-into-several-small-functions-in-c) as well. Imagine how you would write a [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) if you lump all your code into a single function. If you are so worried about the size of the stack frame why don't you write everything in the `main()` function?

BTW, [context switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) does not apply here, it's used to define the process of swapping processes / threads off the processor.

Comment: some research yielded this, [link] (https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-most-important-lesson-youve-learned-as-a-software-engineer)

Comment: @newb7777 The first answer in your link says what Ken Thompson had to say. I think that's enough for mankind in general to see the advantages :)

Answer (score 1):

These are not ["nested functions"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html). It is true that on a poor compiler it would waste more stack. However putting into functions makes the code a) reusable, b) groups related things together.

An optimizing compiler would know to inline the contents of all these functions so the resulting code would be more or less identical for both cases - especially if the functions were declared with *internal linkage* (i.e. the keyword `static`).

Comment: On a silicon like PIC10f where memory is not abundant, smallest code size would be preferred? On PIC32, its probably easier to write with good coding style.